# List and Integer query

Tags: python, list, integer

If i had a list of numbers and some maybe negative, how would i ensure all numbers in my list were positive? I can covert the items in the list to integers thats no problem.

Another question, I want to compare items in my list to an integer value say 'x' and sum all the values in my list that are less than x.

Thank you.

Comment: Define "ensure". What do you want to happen if an item isn't positive?

Comment: Please mark homework with the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list `Ns` of numbers (if it's a list of strings as in several similar questions asked recently each will have to be made into an int, or whatever other kind of number, by calling `int` [[or `float`, etc]] on it), the list of their absolute values (if that's what you mean by "ensure") is

```
[abs(n) for n in Ns]
```

If you mean, instead, to **check** whether all numbers are `>= 0`, then

```
all(n >= 0 for n in Ns)
```

will give you a `bool` value respecting exactly that specification.

The sum of the items of the list that are `<x` is

```
sum(n for n in Ns if n < x)
```

Of course you may combine all these kinds of operations in one sweep (e.g. if you need to take the `abs(n)` as well as checking if it's `< x`, checking if it's `>= 0`, summing, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

```
# input list is named "lst"
pos_list = [int(a) for a in lst if int(a) > 0]
# And num 2 (notice generator is used instead of list)
return sum(a for a in lst if a < x)
```

Comment: Hm ... asker, did you want to throw out the negative numbers or flip their sign?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>mylist = [1,2,3,-2]
>>>any(item for item in mylist if item < 0)
True
>>>mylist.pop()
-2
>>>any(item for item in mylist if item < 0)
False
```

answers your first question.

```
>>> x = 3
>>> sum(item for item in mylist if item < x)
3
```

answers your second question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer / First part:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> max(map(lambda x: x < 0, a))
False

>>> max(map(lambda x: x < 0, b))
True
```

Or just use `min`:

```
>>> min(a) < 0
True

>>> min(b) < 0
False
```

Second part:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> sum(filter(lambda n: n < x, a))
>>> 0

>>> sum(filter(lambda n: n < x, b))
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, I guess you are asking because of some class about functional programming.

In this case, what you are asking for can be accomplished with [functional programming tools](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools) available in Python.
In particular, the first point can be solved using filter, while the second with map and reduce (or, better, with map and sum).